# Python array simple issue

Tags: python, arrays, list

I've the following two arrays:

```
array1 = [0, 1, 1, 0]
array2 = ['foo', 'bar', 'hello', 'bye']
```

I want to save into an array the values of `array2` that has the index `1`in `array1`.

On the example above, the desired result should be `result_array = ['bar', 'hello']`.

I've tried something like this, but it's not working.

```
for i in array1:
  if i = 1:
     result_array.append(array2[i])
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume `if i = 1:` is a typo?

Comment: You should have pointed out that __is not working__ means __throws exception__

Comment: Obligatory comment: Those are not arrays, those are `lists`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modified version of your code which will work is:

```
for i in range(len(array1)):
    if array1[i]:
        result_array.append(array2[i])
```

The problems in your code are:

1) You use `for i in array1`, where i is the temp iterator created to represent the values in the list. So it will always be either 0 or 1, depending on what value of the list it represents

2) `if i=1` is wrong. `=` is assignment operator and `==` should be used to compare values. Since you said the list contains only 0s and 1s, `if i:` us enough

Answer (score 7):

The problem with your code is that you're using `=` in `if` condition, replace it with `==`. And secondly to get the index as well as item you need to use `enumerate`, currently you're appending `array[i]`, so your code will end up appending `'bar'` two times.

```
>>> result_array = []
>>> for i, x in enumerate(array1):
        if x == 1:
            result_array.append(array2[i])
...         
>>> result_array
['bar', 'hello']
```

Another better way to do this is to use `zip` and a list comprehension:

```
>>> [b for a, b in zip(array1, array2) if a==1]
['bar', 'hello']
```

And fastest way to do this is to use [`itertools.compress`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

```
>>> from itertools import compress
>>> list(compress(array2, array1))
['bar', 'hello']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function and [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
print [y for x, y in zip(array1, array2) if x == 1]
```

Or, if you're into [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> array1 = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0])
>>> array2 = np.array(['foo', 'bar', 'hello', 'bye'])
>>> # np.nonzero returns indices of array1 that are, well, non-zero
>>> array2[np.nonzero(array1)]
array(['bar', 'hello'], 
      dtype='|S5')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in only the `1`s in array 1, then you can use `zip` to iterate through multiple list/array at the same time, see http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip (note that zip will ONLY iterate until the length of the shorter list):

```
>>> array1 = [0, 1, 1, 0]
>>> array2 = ['foo', 'bar', 'hello', 'bye']
>>> [j for i,j in zip(array1, array2) if i == 1]
['bar', 'hello']
```

If you want an index of the two arrays using array1 as key in a defaultdict, see http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> array1 = [0, 1, 1, 0]
>>> array2 = ['foo', 'bar', 'hello', 'bye']
>>> array3 = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i,j in zip(array1,array2):
...     array3[i].append(j)
... 
>>> array3[1]
['bar', 'hello']
>>> array3[0]
['foo', 'bye']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import izip
res = [v2 for v1, v2 in izip(array1, array2) if v1==1]
```

You may use simple *zip* instead of *izip* for small lists.